# Blank screen on closing simplemodal pop-up

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, simplemodal

I'm using Simplemodal to open a PDF in an iframe, in a modal pop-up. This works fine in all browsers. In IE11, when I close this pop-up, the entire window goes white. If I view the source,  the website HTML's still there.

This is the jQuery I use:

```
$('a.lightbox_trigger').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var popup = '<iframe src="'+link+'" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900" height="480"></iframe>';
  $.fn.SimpleModal({
    hideFooter: true,
    width: 900,
    title: title,
    model: 'modal',
    contents: popup
  }).showModal();
  return false; 
});
```

This only occurs in IE11, it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('a.lightbox_trigger').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var popup = '<iframe src="'+link+'" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900" height="480"></iframe>';
  $.fn.SimpleModal({
    hideFooter: true,
    width: 900,
    title: title,
    model: 'modal',
    contents: popup,
    overflow : 'none' 
  }).showModal();
$.fn.css('overflow','auto');
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: It is generally helpful if you explain how your code snippet answers the question as otherwise it is not particularly useful to future users who may encounter this same problem.  You can use the `edit` button under your answer to add extra details as needed